# JHipster refuse customization during entity creation

Tags: jhipster

With JHipster , I want to create a entity. I used the following command line :

```
yo jhipster:entity author
```

And have the output :

```
appPath - src/main/webapp
The entity author is being created.
appPath: src/main/webapp
appPath: src/main/webapp
appPath: src/main/webapp
   create src\main\java\fr\par\conferences\domain\Author.java
   create src\main\java\fr\par\conferences\repository\AuthorRepository.java
   create src\main\java\fr\par\conferences\web\rest\AuthorResource.java
   create src\main\webapp\views\authors.html
   create src\main\webapp\scripts\author\router.js
   create src\main\webapp\scripts\author\controller.js
   create src\main\webapp\scripts\author\service.js
   create src\test\java\fr\par\conferences\web\rest\AuthorResourceTest.java
```

JHipster create entity but didn't ask me about entity's fields of relationships. How to force JHipster to ask for it ?

Comment: It depends on the version you are using - which version do you have?

Comment: OK : I use a v0.13 one. A `npm update -g generator-jhipster ` didn't update my JHipster because of a too old nodejs version. After a nodejs update everything turn fine... Thank you !

Comment: does the file .jhipster/author.json exists? this should be on your generated project root folder, if it is, that means that you have generated the entity before, so you can delete such file, and call the generator, or edit the file directly.